# Aggregate multiple columns in a dataframe based on custom functions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, summary

Afternoon All,

I have been trying to resolve this for awhile, any help would be appreciated.

Here is my dataframe:

```
Channel state       rfq_qty
A        Done       10
B        Tied Done  10
C        Done       10
C        Done       10
C        Done       10
C        Tied Done  10
B        Done       10
B        Done       10
```

> I would like to:
>
> 1. Group by channel, then state
> 2. Sum the rfq_qty for each channel
> 3. Count the occurences of each 'done' string in state ('Done' is treated the same as 'Tied Done' i.e. anything with 'done' in it)
> 4. Display the channels rfq_qty as a percentage of the total number of rfq_qty (80)

```
Channel state   rfq_qty Percentage
A         1       10    0.125
B         3       30    0.375
C         4       40    0.5
```

> I have attempted this with the following:

```
df_Done = df[
                (
                    df['state']=='Done'
                ) 
                | 
                (
                    df['state'] == 'Tied Done'
                )
            ][['Channel','state','rfq_qty']]

df_Done['Percentage_Qty']= df_Done['rfq_qty']/df_Done['rfq_qty'].sum()
df_Done['Done_Trades']= df_Done['state'].count()

display(
        df_Done[
                (df_Done['Channel'] != 0)
               ].groupby(['Channel'])['Channel','Count of Done','rfq_qty','Percentage_Qty'].sum().sort_values(['rfq_qty'], ascending=False)
       )
```

> Works but looks convoluted. Any improvements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use:

- first filter by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) and `loc`
- [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate by [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with tuples of new columns names and functions
- add `Percentage` by divide by [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html) and `sum`
- last if necessary [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by `rfq_qty`

---

```
df_Done = df.loc[df['state'].isin(['Done', 'Tied Done']), ['Channel','state','rfq_qty']]

#if want filter all values contains Done
#df_Done = df[df['state'].str.contains('Done')]

#if necessary filter out Channel == 0
#mask = (df['Channel'] != 0) & df['state'].isin(['Done', 'Tied Done'])
#df_Done = df.loc[mask, ['Channel','state','rfq_qty']]

d = {('rfq_qty', 'sum'), ('Done_Trades','size')}
df = df_Done.groupby('Channel')['rfq_qty'].agg(d).reset_index()
df['Percentage'] = df['rfq_qty'].div(df['rfq_qty'].sum())
df = df.sort_values('rfq_qty')
print (df)
  Channel  Done_Trades  rfq_qty  Percentage
0       A            1       10       0.125
1       B            3       30       0.375
2       C            4       40       0.500
```

Comment: Hey Jezzrael. Thanks for that. When I try to sirt on the sum column it fails to sort from largest to smallest.

df.sort_values(['sum'], ascending=False)

Comment: @PeterLucas - just remove `, ascending=False`

Comment: Perfect, case issue on column header. Thanks again!

Comment: @jpp - Hmmm, In my opinion if OP use filtering first and then working with filtered `df_Done` DataFrame then it is no problem.

Comment: @jpp - I agree, so added comment `df_Done = df[df['state'].str.contains('Done')]`

Comment: can I ask on the logic here? 
the 'd' assignment to sum,sum and count, size then agg(d) function, how does this exactly work in the mechanics of the grouping?

Comment: Here `groupby` use column `['rfq_qty']` and aggregate all functions defined in tuples as second value. Simplify solution should be `print ( df_Done.groupby('Channel')['rfq_qty'].agg(['sum','size']))` - then columns names are `sum` and `size`. How aggregation wotking in pandas is possible check in [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166867/discussion-between-peter-lucas-and-jezrael).

Comment: agg(d).reset_index()....by doing this we reset the index and the old index is added as a column?

Why choose rfq_qty as opposed to state given state is also being summarised via the size paramater?

Comment: @PeterLucas - exactly.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a single `df.groupby.agg` and rename columns:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Channel': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'B'],
                   'state': ['Done', 'Tied Done', 'Done', 'Done', 'Done', 'Tied Done', 'Done', 'Done'],
                   'rfq_qty': [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]})

agg_funcs = {'state': lambda x: x[x.str.contains('Done')].count(),
             'rfq_qty': ['sum', lambda x: x.sum() / df['rfq_qty'].sum()]}

res = df.groupby('Channel').agg(agg_funcs).reset_index()
res.columns = ['Channel', 'state', 'rfq_qty', 'Percentage']

#   Channel  state  rfq_qty  Percentage
# 0       A      1       10       0.125
# 1       B      3       30       0.375
# 2       C      4       40       0.500
```

This isn't the *most efficient* way, since it relies of non-vectorised aggregations, but it may be a good option if it is performant for your use case.